# how to demonstrate functor's MAP method associative property

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, functor

I read that a functor's map is assocative and that it implies the following :

```
Functor.map(f).map(g) == Functor.map(x => g(f(x))
```

Shouldn't the above equation be written like this to demonstrate associativity?

```
Functor.map(f).map(g) == Functor.map(f.map(g))
```

(but it seams impossible because funcitons dont have a map method).

There is something that I am not grasping here.

Comment: Have you considered that `f.map(g) = (x => g(f(x)))`?

Comment: sure, but a function doesn't have a map method does it ?

Comment: You have just discovered that functions are not an instance of functor in Javascript.

Comment: What is your `Functor` thing in JavaScript? Do you want to understand functors in general, or do you have some specific js code to work with?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example in Haskell.
You can create two functions.
The first `composeAndMap` which will first compose `f` and `g` and then apply the map function.

```
composeAndMap :: Functor f => (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> f a -> f c
composeAndMap f g = fmap (f . g)
```

The second will be called `mapAndCompose` which will compose two partial application functions using the map function. The first map will use the `f` and the second one will use the `g` like this:

```
mapAndCompose :: Functor f => (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> f a -> f c
mapAndCompose f g = fmap f . fmap g
```

Eventually you can compare between the results of each function using a specific functor instance, the most obvious is the list functor.

```
list :: [Int]
list = [1..5]

main :: IO ()
main = print $ mapAndCompose (+1) (+2) list == composeAndMap (+1) (+2) list
```

You should not forget the identity law also.

```
identity :: Functor f => f a -> f a
identity = fmap id

composeAndMap :: Functor f => (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> f a -> f c
composeAndMap f g = fmap (f . g)

mapAndCompose :: Functor f => (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> f a -> f c
mapAndCompose f g = fmap f . fmap g

list :: [Int]
list = [1..5]

main :: IO ()
main = do 
  print $ identity list == list    
  print $ mapAndCompose (+1) (+2) list == composeAndMap (+1) (+2) list
```

This is an example in JavaScript:
Create two functions `plusOne` and `plusTwo`

```
function plusOne(val) {
    return val + 1;
}

function plusTwo(val) {
    return val + 2;
}
```

Create a `compose` function which composes two functions

```
function compose(f, g) {
    return (val) => f(g(val));
}
```

Create a utility function `sequenceEquals`

```
function sequenceEquals(arr1, arr2) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;        
}
```

Now you can compare between the two implementations:

```
let list = [1,2,3,4,5];
let composed = compose(plusOne, plusTwo);
let composeAndMap = list.map(composed);
let mappedTwice = list.map(plusTwo).map(plusOne);

console.log(sequenceEquals(composeAndMap, mappedTwice));
```

And the identity law.
Create an identity function:

```
function identity(value) { return value; }
```

And compare the results:

```
console.log(sequenceEquals(list.map(identity), list));
```